# PHP query not showing all results in html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have the following query to show all users from my database:

```
<ul class="names">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Navn</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Score</th>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'users', 'password'); //The Blank string is the password
                    mysql_select_db('users');

                    $query = ("SELECT * FROM oneusers"); //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
                    $result = mysql_query($query);

                    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
                    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['iUserName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['iUserEmail'] . "</td><td>" . $row['iUserCash'] . " DKK</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
                    }

                    mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
                    ?>
                    </table>
                </ul>
```

But for some reason it doesnt show all the data.

In only shows the user with iUserId 2 and not one.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be wrong?

I can log in with iUserId 1's credentials, and it shows fine the info on the login page.

But not here :S

Comment: It's $CURRENT_YEAR, stop using `mysql_` functions. They're going to be removed very soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove line `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

Because this line starts to fetching records from your query results. First fetched record is record with id `1` and you do nothing with it.

Then you start `echo`ing other records, but record with id `1` is already skipped.

Comment: Ahh.. I see ! Thank you very much ! :D

Answer (score 3):

You fetch the first row before your while loop is defined; once you enter the while loop it fetches the next row, which is the second. Remove the first `mysql_fetch_array($result)` operation.

Incidentally, also, the original `mysql` api in PHP is deprecated, it is recommended to use `mysqli` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put it this way though

```
    <?php
                        $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'users', 'password'); //The Blank string is the password
                        mysql_select_db('users');
let all the connection be outside the "ul" tag.

$query = ("SELECT * FROM oneusers"); //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
                        $result = mysql_query($query);
$query = ("SELECT * FROM oneusers"); //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
                        $result = mysql_query($query);

                        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    ?>
<ul class="names">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Navn</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Score</th>
                        </tr>
                    <?php

                    while($row){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
                    echo "<tr><td>" . $row['iUserName'] . "</td><td>" . $row['iUserEmail'] . "</td><td>" . $row['iUserCash'] . " DKK</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
                    }

                    mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
                    ?>
                    </table>
                </ul>
```

Comment: What do you think `while ($row)` is going to do? Hint: where does the value of `$row` get changed?

Comment: $row=mysql_fetch_array($result); this creates the array and then while($row) loops through. i'm saying put your connection code outside the <ul> or on top of the page or may in a separate file and include it

Comment: Yes. Specifically, it loads the first results into `$row`. But you never change the value of `$row` in your loop, so `while ($row)` while loop endlessly if there's any data to show.